# iOS UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource reloads all data with no changes

Tags: ios, uikit, ios13, diffabledatasource, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

I have a simple `UICollectionView` with 1 section and 1 item type powered by new iOS 13 `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`.

Even with no changes to data source (identical `hashValue`s), `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` updates whole collection view (calls `cellProvier` for every visible cell).

The thing is, the same scenario with `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` works as expected, that is with no changes to data source `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` **does nothing**.

Is this difference by design, or is this some kind of Bug?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue too :(